# Setting for Chrome/Firefox/etc to auto-block video/audio

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, audio, video, browser

We've all seen the browser features that ask permission to use flash, display notifications, popups, etc.

In some cases, there's not even a popup - just an icon is shown and you have to manually go find and whitelist the site to get the content working.

I'd like this to happen in firefox/chrome, etc with videos and audio.

Preferrably, it'd be great if the browser just didn't load / display video elements at all unless I whitelisted the domain in the browser / clicked 'Allow' somewhere.

We're being bombarded with autoplay videos all over the internet, when we really only 'watch' videos on a handful of sites.

Is there a setting somewhere deep in chrome/firefox that would allow me to tell it to ask permission for displaying videos? Not just autoplay - since that frequently doesn't actually stop the videos - but actually not rendering it?

Comment: You could just write a userscript that hides all `video` elements. Which doesn't mean they won't get loaded of course…

Answer (score 0):

You could just wait. Firefox is bringing blocking for autoplay in their new release.

Link: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2019/02/firefox-66-to-block-automatically-playing-audible-video-and-audio/